# How to get rid of the Package does not exist exception?

Tags: java

I have a java source file called FileAdd.java in the folder **Implementation Logic** which imports the class on the **BusinessClasses** folder . But the the compiler is throwing an error that the pacakge **BusinessClasses** does not exist
though I am using the statement

```
import BusinessClasses.ParamClass
```

in the command prompt I am using the statement in the Implementation Logic Folder

```
javac FileAdd.java
```

the folder structure is as follows :

[image]

Comment: Your `BusinessClasses` package is not on the classpath, most likely because you're compiling a specific file. This looks like an entire project, why are you compiling only a file?

Comment: Your Tomcat deployment is different to your java code

Comment: You should use a build tool like Maven to do this. It will make sure everything is where it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Try `javac -cp .. FileAdd.java`.

The `cp ..` option tells the compiler to use the parent folder as the class path (where to find additional classes). Since your BusinessClasses folder is located there as well, the import statement should work.

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief. This explanation would be useful for OP and other readers who read your post.